# Vector field of charges

Tags: plotting, vector

I wanted to plot vector field of 12 positive charges Standing in a circular way with a positive charge at the center all same magnitude. I do not know how to start. Can you please help me
Thanks.

Comment: Look up `VectorPlot` or `VectorPlot3D` depending on whether it's in the plane or in space.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: can you upload sketch hand draw of what you mean!?

Answer (score 2):

Electric field lines for 12 negative (left) and 12 positive (right) charges located on a circle

```
p = Table[{Cos[x], Sin[x], 0}, {x, 0, 2 Pi - Pi/6, Pi/6}];

U[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Sum[1/Sqrt[({x, y, z} - p[[i]]).({x, y, z} - p[[i]])], {i, Length[p]}]

Efield = Grad[U[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

StreamDensityPlot[{Efield[[1]], Efield[[2]]} /. z -> 0.1, {x, -1.5, 
  1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 StreamStyle -> LightGray, StreamPoints -> Fine]

StreamDensityPlot[{-Efield[[1]], -Efield[[2]]} /. z -> 0.05, {x, -1.5,
   1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 StreamStyle -> LightGray, StreamPoints -> Fine]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Electric field lines for 12 negative (left) and 12 positive (right) charges located on a circle + one in the center

```
p = Table[{Cos[x], Sin[x], 10^-3}, {x, 0, 2 Pi - Pi/6, Pi/6}];

U[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Sum[1/Sqrt[({x, y, z} - p[[i]]).({x, y, z} - p[[i]])], {i, 
    Length[p]}] + 1/Sqrt[{x, y, z}.{x, y, z}]

Efield = Grad[U[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

StreamDensityPlot[{Efield[[1]], Efield[[2]]} /. z -> 0.1, {x, -1.5, 
  1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 StreamStyle -> LightGray, StreamPoints -> Fine]

StreamDensityPlot[{-Efield[[1]], -Efield[[2]]} /. z -> 0.05, {x, -1.5,
   1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
 StreamStyle -> LightGray, StreamPoints -> Fine]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Many thanks, how is it like when a same charge is placed at the center?

Comment: @ElaheLashgari Do you ask or answer?

Comment: I asked what if we put a charge with same magnitude and positive right at the center of each circle, how the field looks like then? So imagin we have 13 positive charges instead of 12

Comment: @ElaheLashgari See update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, just a question, what does this line mean? What is P[[i]] here?Sum[1/Sqrt[({x, y, z} - p[[i]]).({x, y, z} - p[[i]])], {i, 
    Length[p]}] + 1/Sqrt[{x, y, z}.{x, y, z}

Comment: Thanks, just a question, what does this line mean? What is P[[i]] here?Sum[1/Sqrt[({x, y, z} - p[[i]]).({x, y, z} - p[[i]])], {i, Length[p]}] + 1/Sqrt[{x, y, z}.{x, y, z} –

Comment: @ElaheLashgari See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law

Answer (score 1):

This is beginning you can do the rest!

```
or = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}];
g1 = ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
pp = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}];
g2 = ListPlot[pp, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}];
Show[g1, g2, or]
```

[image]

Comment: Great,many Thanks it is a big help

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to plot it’s electric field vector. Can you please help me with that.